A variant of Campbell (1897) identity (related to BCH formula)
Campbell's identity (see in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) takes the form:
$$ e^XYe^{-X}\equiv ad_{e^X}Y=e^{ad_X}Y\equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{[(X)^n,Y]}{n!},$$
where $$[(X)^n,Y]=[X,...,[X,Y]...]$$ means the $n$-nested commutators with the Xs on the left.
Can we find a similar expression also for the series:
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{[(X)^n,Y]}{(n+1)!},$$
i.e., is there an analytic expression with exponentials of $X$ and maybe other functions of it?
As a first direction, I tried:
$$ [X,S]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{[(X)^{n+1},Y]}{(n+1)!}=(e^{ad_X}-\mathbb{I})Y, $$
but then I need to "invert" the operator $[X,.]$.
If it helps, in my case, the operator $X$ assumes the form $i\sum_{nm}\sigma_x^{(n)}\sigma_x^{(m)}$, where $\sigma_x^{(n)}$ is the x-pauli matrix acting on the $n$th qubit (the system consists of $N$ qubits). The operator $Y$ is hermitian.

One way to prove the identity is to consider it as $$e^{sX}Ye^{-sX}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{[sX,[\cdots,Y]\cdots]}{n!}$$ and then setting $s=1$; so the integral from $s=0$ to $s=1$ trivially obtains what you want, although I'm not sure if this integral would be easy to write down, nor if it would even be useful to express it so.

Sounds interesting, I will try that and report back :)

Hey, so apparently, the integral equation boils down to the last equation I wrote in the question.
